# Parsing "difficult" xml element with SimpleXml

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am trying to parse the "**No**" which in the tp:Foreign->tp:No

```
<tp:CompanyData>
  <tp:TransactionWithoutPrice>
   <tp:Foreign>
     <tp:No>true</tp:No>
   </tp:Foreign>
  </tp:TransactionWithoutPrice>
</tp:CompanyData>
```

This is my code and it works, it is returning me the **No**. This iy my code:

```
echo $value = $xml->children('tp', true)->CompanyData->TransactionWithoutPrice->Foreign->children('tp', true)->getName();
```

My question is: Is this the correct way ? Can i also do it with less code ?

Comment: I think you are right

Comment: *`This is my code and it works`* - there are many ways to solve a single problem, are you asking why this works or how else to solve this?

Comment: i edit my question. My question is: Is this the correct way ? Can i also do it with less code ?

Comment: Then this looks like [it belongs on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: To begin with, the sample xml in your question isn't well formed. Can you edit your question to fix that?

Comment: Those are namespaces. You could use the namespace identifier instead of the `tp` prefix if you want to make it more robust (that's what `children()`s second argument controls) but this is pretty much the less verbose syntax.